# Arquillian - Component already defined in module

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to setup Arquillian and I'm always getting a stacktrace:

```
13:37:29,432 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."6bf136f5-6ea1-43e0-a521-76250a489921.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."6bf136f5-6ea1-43e0-a521-76250a489921.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "6bf136f5-6ea1-43e0-a521-76250a489921.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011046: A component named 'ValidationServiceImpl' is already defined in this module
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.EEModuleDescription.addComponent(EEModuleDescription.java:137)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EJBComponentDescriptionFactory.addComponent(EJBComponentDescriptionFactory.java:60)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.processSessionBeans(SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.java:157)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(SessionBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.java:86)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
```

My arquillian test is setup in the following way:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ECadDocumentServiceImplTestIT {
private static final boolean RECURSIVE = true;

static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ECadDocumentServiceImplTestIT.class);

@Inject
private ECadDocumentService eCadDocumentService;

@Deployment
public static WebArchive getServiceDeployment() {
    File settingsFile = new File(System.getProperty("maven.execution.global-settings"));
    File pomFile = new File(System.getProperty("maven.execution.pom-file"));

    File[] libs = Maven.configureResolver()
            .fromFile(settingsFile)
            .loadPomFromFile(pomFile)
            .importRuntimeAndTestDependencies().resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

    WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addAsLibraries(libs)
            .addPackages(true, ECadDocumentService.class.getPackage())
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
    return war;
}


@Test
public void test() throws EcadError {
    ApplicationIdentification applicationIdent = ApplicationIdentificationMother.valid(0);
    DocumentTreatmentResponse dtr = eCadDocumentService.addDocument(ApplicantIdentityMother.valid(), applicationIdent, DocumentIdentificationMother.valid(), DocumentFingerprintMother.valid());
    assertEquals(applicationIdent.getApplicationId(), dtr.getApplicationID());
}
```

}

I'm adding the libs because I'm using the apache.commons.net dependency. Otherwise I'm getting a "classNotFoundException".

Has anyone got any idea? I haven't got a class named ´ValidationServiceImpl´ twice.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the duplicated class is into the ECadDocumentService's package and in some library that you resolve from the pom file.
Try to share more information about the layout of you project or at least the location of the test and problematic classes and the dependencies on your own projects included in the pom.file from you get the libraries.

You can save the deployment archive (before it is deployed) adding the next option to the  arquillian.xml file.

```
<engine>
    <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/deployments</property>
</engine>
```

There is more information about it in the section Export the Deployment here [arquillian guide](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/)

Regards